# Showing posts in the website based on the document ID

Tags: php, security

I'm creating a `php` website in which I have a `document.php` that basically takes a `did (document ID)` and displays it. An example would be `mysite.com/document.php?did=1` which grabs the document content from database with a query like `SELECT * FROM documents WHERE id=1`. I know the security issues with this approach (such as SQL Injection) and I both do both validation and escaping but one thing that some guy told me was that it can be pretty easy to create a crawler that does something like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3000; ++i) 
   DownloadPage("mysite.com/document.php?did="+i);
```

Now I have 2 questions.

1. Is this really an issue with the code that I've written or is there another solution for this? For instance, I know that I can tell Apache server to limit the bandwidth usage for one IP. (Or maybe a better alternative presented by you.)
2. If this is an issue, I have a solution in my mind. I think I should add another parameter to the page. Something like the hash for the content which will be checked against the DB to see if this is the correct URL.

One thing that I've seen around a lot is that sometimes some part of the title is appended to the URL. Something like this:
`mysite.com/document/1/some_part_of_the_url` but I've checked and if I remove the title and go to `mysite.com/document/1` it will still show the same webpage. This made me think that this is not for security reasons and is more like a way to help the user find out what is the title of the page he's going to.

Comment: If nothing else, using the title in the URL will help you with SEO. No one is going to search for "Post #1" in Google :)

Comment: are documents available to all viewers of the page, or only to logged-in users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that the title is generally appended to the URL is for search engine optimisation.

Are the documents supposed to be secure? If so, you need to implement some kind of authentication. Security by obscurity e.g. the user won't guess the ID is not a good way to do it. You could quite easily implement a username/password, even if the username/password is baked into the code, and then use sessions to check the user is authenticated.

If the documents are not secured then I don't really see any need to worry about authentication. Consider that on SO you could access questions by just going to stackoverflow.com/questions/#{id}.

Comment: Thanks. This (as well as all other answers) is what I thought would be correct. That's the reason I first asked if is it really something wrong with my code or not?! And for the first part (adding some part of the title to the URL), how can I do it in php? I would very much appreciate your help.

Comment: What you want to look into is canonical URLS using mod_rewrite. Google it and you will find plenty of tutorials

Answer (score 1):

The some_part_of_the_url is to provide a degree of human-readability in the url for the benefit of web-crawlers such as googlebots that index pages... a higher human-readability affects the "weighting" of that page in search results. It isn't done for security reasons.

Rather than assigning the document id as an autoincrement, you could assign a hash value so that they would not be sequential numbers, but this adds complexity to your code... autoincrement for setting record ids is useful.

You're better restricting this at the webserver level rather than the script level (script still needs to start running to do any tests if you apply this at the script level)

Answer (score 1):

One thing I do not understand is, how does this becomes a security issue?

- Let someone use crawler, for you, it is same like an user accessing a page, right? So what's wrong in it?
- If you want to prevent or limit access to it, you can either use your `php session` features and control it.
- If you want to prevent an user invariably using ids, you should control it through your logic that if such session user is allowed an access to your particular document id (lot of logical ways to acheive it.)

Note that, most of the security issues can be prevent by STRICTLY checking for the EXPECTED INPUTS ONLY, rather than thinking of numerous solutions.

Now this was the preventing through coding part of your application.

But security is not just this, a wrongly configured server, networks, etc can also create problems for you.